# Tailwind: is there any special reason behind enclosing 'raw' key in single quotation?

Tags: css, next.js, tailwind-css, tailwind-ui

in the Tailwind [custom media queries](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/screens#custom-media-queries) documentation, we are given an option to create a fully custom breakpoint using the 'raw' key.

I added this in my configuration file and when I save file, Prettier automatically removes the single quotation (' ') from raw key. So, ('raw') becomes (raw).

I wanted to ask that is it all fine - or should it be exactly enclosed in single quotation.

If anyone can explain reason, I'll be highly thankful.

I explored the Tailwind docs but couldn't find a satisfactory answer.

Answer (score 0):

`'raw'` and `raw` are equivalent when used as an object key in JavaScript, so it is fine that you use `raw`.

Object keys do not need be quoted in object initialization syntax if either:

- The key has only numbers.
- The key starts with a letter and only contains letters, numbers and underscores.

This is behavior of JavaScript syntax rather than Tailwind, hence why it was not mentioned in their documentation.